# save pandas' to_html' as a file

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DateFrame 'tsod', now I convert it to html:

```
tsod.to_html()
```

How can I save this as a file? better save as a '.html' file.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
with open('my_file.html', 'w') as fo:
    fo.write(tsod.to_html())
```

or alternatively using pandas

```
tsod.to_html(open('my_file.html', 'w'))
```

or again (thanks @andy-hayden)

```
with open('my_file.html', 'w') as fo:
    tsod.to_html(fo)
```

Comment: I don't think `tsod.to_html('my_file.html')` will work.  `to_html` doesn't accept a string, it accepts something it can write to, whether an open file or a StringIO buffer (it looks for `.write()`).  You could use `tsod.to_html(fo)`, though.

Comment: Using StringIO is probably another way to solve this... write the html to a string, dump the string to a file.

Comment: I think the good practice here is to still use with around the pandas bit: `tsod.to_html(fo)`.

Comment: Anyone that happens to find this now, `to_html` does take strings now so to name it just `tsod.to_html('Name.html')`.

Answer (score 5):

As of the current version of pandas `tsod.to_html('out.html')` works fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
a=tsod.to_html()
save(a,'path')
```

will work

Comment: What is `save()`? That's not a python builtin function - hint, try adding an `import` statement.