# How to annotate labels when you hover over a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-styles

I have a `pandas` dataframe that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
foo = pd.DataFrame({'temp': ['message1', 'message2', 'message3'], 'var2': [1,2,3], 'col3':[4,5,6]})
```

I also have the following dictionary

```
foo_dict = {'message1' : 'i am message 1', 'message2': 'i am foo',  'message3': 'i am lala', 'var2' : ' another random message', 'col3': 'more random messages'}
```

I would like to style this pandas dataframe, so that whenever I hover over an element of the dataframe, if this element (can be either a cell, or a column) exists in the `foo_dict.keys()`, i would like the respective `foo_dict.value()` to be annotated

Is it possible in pandas ?

Comment: I cannot add the desired output, because I cannot annotate values in a pandas dataframe

Comment: In what medium are you looking to use the hover feature; Jupyter Notebook?  Perhaps an example of why or how you would use this would be useful.

Comment: There's no built-in feature that will do what you're asking

Comment: @S3DEV I want to use it on a streamlit up, so i suppose it is in an HTML framework

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As part of the the [Styler Enhancements](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v1.3.0.html#styler-enhancements) in pandas 1.3.0 there is now a [`set_tooltips`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.io.formats.style.Styler.set_tooltips.html) function which can be used to set tool tips for the cells in the DataFrame.

Note, this is currently limited to "string based tooltips [that] are only applicable to `<td>` HTML elements, and cannot be used for column or index headers."

```
import pandas as pd

foo = pd.DataFrame({
    'temp': ['message1', 'message2', 'message3'],
    'var2': [1, 2, 3],
    'col3': [4, 5, 6]
})

# Setup a DataFrame with corresponding hover values
tooltips_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'temp': ['i am message 1', 'i am foo', 'i am lala'],
    'var2': ' another random message',
    'col3': 'more random messages'
})

# Assign tooltips
foo.style.set_tooltips(tooltips_df)
```

[image: styled table with hover tooltips]

Comment: and to export to html you can change the last line to 
`foo.style.set_tooltips(tooltips_df).to_html('out.html')` 
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/36428285/5233269