# How to add information about a column in a column header?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, label

Is there a way to add information labels or boxes to the column headers of a pandas DataFrame that can provide additional information on that column, similar to adding a text box with comments in an Excel cell?

I have tried adding a multi-index to the data of the DataFrame, but it gives you another typically short way of writing some additional information grouped on columns, whereas I am looking for something that is not always visible but whose attribute can be called when extra information needed. The other solution would be to have a separate dictionary with column headers and the label information. I would like to integrate it into DataFrame, though.

Comment: Welcome to the community. You might want to refer [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to annotate labels when you hover over a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63271761/how-to-annotate-labels-when-you-hover-over-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.